# How do I create and import a class in GDScript

Tags: godot, gdscript

I would like to create and import a class in GDScript.  Here is some non-functional pseudo code to explain what I'm trying to do:

```
class_name WordPrinter

var my_word: String

func _init(word: String)
  my_word = word

func print_word()
  print(my_word)
```

```
const word_printer = import("./word_printer.gd").new("Hello World")

word_printer.print_word()
```

I've found various tutorials on classes and imports, but I have yet to find a straightforward code example that works.  Here are some places I've looked:

- https://www.javatpoint.com/godot-classes-in-gdscript
- https://coderwall.com/p/anrtcg/how-to-import-script-in-godot
- https://godottutorials.com/courses/introduction-to-gdscript/godot-tutorials-gdscript-15/
- https://gdscript.com/tutorials/classes/

The second link above does show working code, but the imported class does not have any type definitions, and is not very useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have specified a `class_name` for your class:

```
class_name WordPrinter

var my_word: String

func _init(word: String)
  my_word = word

func print_word()
  print(my_word)
```

Thus, you should be able to use it directly:

```
func _ready():
    var say_hello := WordPrinter.new("Hello World")
    say_hello.print_word()
```

By the way, here I'm setting the type of `say_hello` implicitly by using `:=`. We can do it explicitly too:

```
func _ready():
    var say_hello:WordPrinter = WordPrinter.new("Hello World")
    say_hello.print_word()
```

---

And yes, you could instead use `preload` with the path:

```
const word_printer := preload("res://path/to/word_printer.gd")
```

The `preload` is resolved while the script is being parsed, which is how this is a constant expression (and thus can be set to a `const`).

In this case `word_printer` holds a `GDScript` object, which you can use like this:

```
func _ready():
    var say_hello := word_printer.new("Hello World")
    say_hello.print_word()
```

And setting the type explicitly still works:

```
func _ready():
    var say_hello:word_printer = word_printer.new("Hello World")
    say_hello.print_word()
```

---

Since what you are actually using is a `GDScript` object, the same should also work if you get it by other means. For example using `load`, which would allow you to use a variable for the path (for example if you want to decide dynamically which script to load):

```
func _ready():
    var my_word_printer := load("res://path/to/word_printer.gd")
    var say_hello = my_word_printer.new("Hello World")
    say_hello.print_word()
```

However, since `load` is resolved in runtime (instead of being resolved while parsing the script like `preload`) Godot does not know the type until runtime.

Consequently, the variable instantiated from the the script cannot be statically typed (it will be a Variant), and we won't get auto-completion.

Despite not having auto-completion the code still works in runtime.

---

This is all covered in the official documentation under [Classes](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/gdscript/gdscript_basics.html#classes) and under [Static typing](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/gdscript/static_typing.html).

---

*Addendum: You don't need `class_name` for `preload` or `load` to work.*

Answer (score 0):

Importing a class in gdscript can be done with the `preload()` command.  To make the code above usable, all that needs to change is the import line, like so:

```
const word_printer = import("res://path/to/word_printer.gd")

func _ready():
  var say_hello = word_printer.new("Hello World")
  say_hello.print_word()
```

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean to write `preload` instead of `import`?